# Referencing page class in another file

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces, code-behind, vs-web-site-project

I'm not sure why this isn't working, but, when I build my `ASP.NET` WebSite, I get the following error when the referenced namespace is in a ***different*** file than the referencing class.  When the two classes are in the ***same*** file, everything builds fine.

***Error    2   The type or namespace name 'someSpace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) CaseEvaluationPanel.ascx.cs 26  3   ExaminerGradeSheet***

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
namespace someSpace
{
    public class EmptyClass : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public int someInt;
    }
}
```

**CaseEvaluationPanel.ascx.cs**

```
public class referencingClass : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public void someMethod()
    {
        someSpace.EmptyClass anEmptyClass = new someSpace.EmptyClass();

        int someInt = anEmptyClass.someInt;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Saunders, ok point taken.  I won't do this in future posts.

Comment: @mason, this is an ASP.NET WebSite so I _guess_ the answer is no, each page is in a separate, automatically generated assembly.  Is this the problem?  If so, how can I "reference" another ASP.NET page assembly?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code as shown below.

```
namespace someSpace
{
    public class EmptyClass : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public int someInt;
    }
}

namespace someSpace
{
     public class referencingClass : System.Web.UI.UserControl
     {
         public void someMethod()
         {
             EmptyClass anEmptyClass = new EmptyClass();

             int someInt = anEmptyClass.someInt;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: yeah I though that would work too; sadly, it doesn't.  Can anyone verify?